# How to clean up .gpx data before writing to a .csv file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, gpx

I am trying to extract specific data from a .gpx file.
The data required is 'trkpt' and 'ele', which is location and elevation data.
My code listed below does pretty much what I need it to do, but it looks messy, and I only need the numerical data.

```
gpx_list = []
gpx = open('G:\\14022705.gpx', 'r')  
for line in gpx:
    info = line.split(',')
    if 'trkpt ' in line:
        gpx_list.append(info)
        print line
    if 'ele' in line:
        gpx_list.append(info)
        print line

gpx_list_out = open('G:\\Position_Data2.csv', 'w')  
for line in gpx_list:
    gpx_list_out.write(line[0])

gpx_list_out.close()
```

Output Example:

```
['<trkpt lat="-42.6150634" lon="+147.4397831">']
['<ele>1.431</ele>']
```

Instead I would like it to look like:
`-42.6150634, +147.4397831, 1.431` all on one line

Any tips on achieving this would be appreciated. I have tried for hours messing around with adding different bits of code but have failed to achieve desired outcome!

Comment: Ok, not sure why my output example showed up like it did? This is how it should have looked:

Comment: ['<trkpt lat="-42.6150634" lon="+147.4397831">']
['<ele>1.431</ele>']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to incorporate this into your code. The regular expression extracts all digits in each line

```
import re

gpx_list = []
gpx = open('G:\\14022705.gpx', 'r')      
gpx_list_out = open('G:\\Position_Data2.csv', 'w') 

for line in gpx:
    if 'trkpt ' in line:
      print re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+",line)
      numerical_value=re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+",line)
      gpx_list_out.write(",".join(numerical_value))

gpx_list_out.close()
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tried that and got ['-42.6150634', '+147.4397831']
['1.431'], which really tidies it up. Doesn't want to write to the csv file though, which is strange as it was before!

Comment: @student2014 how does your gpx file look like? Can you post one line?

Comment: This is the first bit of the original file: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<gpx creator="NC" version="2.0" >

<metadata>
<link href="http://www.mikrokopter.de">
<text>MikroKopter</text>
</link>
<desc>FC HW:2.1 SW:2.0a + NC HW:2.0 SW:2.0a</desc>
</metadata>

<trk>
<name>Flight</name>
<trkseg>
<trkpt lat="-42.6150634" lon="+147.4397831">
<ele>1.431</ele>
<time>2014-02-27T04:32:22Z</time>

Comment: Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Yes. I changed the code but since you have an XML file I recommend that you use some XML parser, for instance Beautifulsoup